# How exactly does tensor contraction work with higher rank tensors?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, quantum-mechanics

I'm an undergraduate student doing my best to learn about tensor networks, but I'm stuck on Equation (2) of this paper "A Practical Introduction to Tensor Networks: Matrix Product States and Projected Entangled Pair States" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2164), which is

$$
F_{\gamma\omega\rho\sigma} = \sum^D_{\alpha,\beta,\delta,\nu,\mu=1} A_{\alpha\beta\delta\sigma} B_{\beta\gamma\mu} C_{\delta\nu\mu\omega}E_{\nu\rho\alpha}
$$

Are the variables that the author chose to contract over arbitrary? Or are they a result of coinciding dimensions, like how $\beta$ is the second dimension of *A* and first dimension of *B*, or how the same relationship is present for $\nu$ in *C* and *E*?

It may be that I'm focusing **way** too hard on the details, but I want to know how the indices of *C* and *E* collapse/contract to be compatible with *B* and so on (**IF** it is the case that this contraction happens because indices coincide).

Thank you!

Comment: Q. "Are the variables that the author chose to contract over arbitrary?" A. Yes. You could rename $\alpha,\beta,\delta,\nu,\mu$ to any other dummy indices from your favourite alphabet, with the sole exception that you cannot use  $\gamma,\omega,\rho,\sigma\,.$ You can also use that formula to contract over *any* other selection of indices. Wait until you have seen more formulas. Press on.